# Setting default font family with theme.json

Tags: block-editor, json

I've searched online and have not been able to find any answers to this one. I am in the middle of developing a new website and have started trying to work with the new theme.json feature in WordPress 5.8.

I've had no problems setting the layout width and defining a color pallette, however, when it then comes to setting a custom font family the editor doesn't seem to pick this up.

I have enqueued the custom Google font:

```
function prefix_block_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-editor-font', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
}
    
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'prefix_block_styles' );
```

And then I have this as my current theme.json:

```
{
    "version":1,
    "settings": {
        "typography": {
            "fontFamilies": [
                {
                    "fontFamily": "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                    "slug": "helvetica-arial",
                    "name": "Helvetica or Arial"
                },
                {
                    "fontFamily": "\"Ubuntu\", sans-serif",
                    "slug": "ubuntu-sansserif",
                    "name": "Ubuntu"
                }
            ]
        },
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "1600px",
            "wideSize": "1600px"
        }
    }
}
```

When I then refresh the editor, it still loads in serif.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: So your `theme.json` file is indeed being loaded correctly? (Did you put it in `wp-content/themes/your-theme/theme.json`?) And are you saying the `layout` option works properly, but not the `fontFamilies` option? Have you tried clearing your caches? Have you double-checked that the Google font is also being loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly where the theme.json sits. The `layout` options are working and I have also been able to add `color` options with no problems, it's only the `fontFamily` option that doesn't seem to work. I checked the source code and the Google font is being loaded. I have also cleared the cache.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and I find out how to solve it:

For each "fontFamily" inside "fontFamilies" array, you get a custom variable.
From your example You can use both variables on your stylesheet or in theme.json:

```
--wp--preset--font-family--helvetica-arial
--wp--preset--font-family--ubuntu-sansserif
```

And then you call the font like this:

```
{
    "version":1,
    "settings": {
        "typography": {
            "fontFamilies": [
                {
                    "fontFamily": "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                    "slug": "helvetica-arial",
                    "name": "Helvetica or Arial"
                },
                {
                    "fontFamily": "\"Ubuntu\", sans-serif",
                    "slug": "ubuntu-sansserif",
                    "name": "Ubuntu",
                    "google": "family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap",

                }
            ]
        },
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "1600px",
            "wideSize": "1600px"
        }
    },
    "styles": {
        "typography": {
            "fontFamily": "var(--wp--preset--font-family--ubuntu-sansserif)",
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes you need to activate / deactivate your theme.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried implementing this on my theme.json file but its now working in the editor. When inspecting I actually can't see the `--wp--preset--font-family--ubuntu-sansserif` being loaded at all. I can see my colors and font sizes but no fontFamilies.

Comment: Additionally, I have managed to set the font family in a `custom` CSS variable using the method describe in the [dev docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#how-settings-under-custom-create-new-css-custom-properties) but again when I try to set the styles > typography > fontFamily property to that custom variable it isn't loading. I'm starting to think that the `fontFamily` property has an issue.

Comment: It's good to understand that --wp--preset--font-family is a prefix to add with the slug of the font. For instance if I would put a font family Montserrat with montserrat slug, the complete variable would be "--wp--preset--font-family--montserrat". It's also important to say that theme.json has an "elements" object which I could define each element's typography attribute like h1, h2, link, etc.

Comment: @KKBSE2016 the example above had some typos in there, that would render it invalid json. i now removed them, not sure when stackexchange will approve my edit. but for now: the last item inside an array/object should not have a trailing comma. so this could be the reason for not working on your end. i implemented it in my current project and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, `typography.fontFamilies` is only available in the Gutenberg plugin. The plugin must be installed for this setting to take effect. See the comparison toggle at https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#settings